# Can Jews buy commercial challah at Whole Foods?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, challah-shabbat-bread

I know Whole Foods supermarkets have challah bread. I am not Jewish. But I once bought challah bread at Whole Foods and ate the whole bread in one sitting. It tasted like . . . bread. I am aware that the Hui people in China would have Muslim-friendly restaurants, and non-Muslim Chinese people would eat in them. But Whole Foods is different. Whole Foods is just a non-religious American supermarket chain. Can Jewish customers buy challah bread at Whole Foods?

Comment: To VTCers: What is psak-seeking or unclear about this question?

Answer (score 1):

Jewish law requires that Jews restrict their food consumption to food that is kosher. Food from non-Jewish supermarket chains can be kosher, and generally Jews will eat it if it is certified as such. There are a large number of agencies that certify food as kosher, and some are considered more reliable or higher quality than others. You can recognize a food as certified kosher it if contains one of the symbols shown on [this list](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) of certifications approved by the Chicago Rabbinical Council (a well-known and widely-accepted kosher authority).

Some of the more common symbols that you'll see on a product that signify that it is kosher are the Orthodox Union's symbol:

[image: Orthodox Union symbol]

and OK Kosher's symbol:

[image: OK Kosher symbol]

---

For bread specifically, there are certain additional stringencies that some Jews observe (i.e. [pas Yisrael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91527/1713) and [yoshon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49070/1713)). The packaging will typically indicate if the bread meets the requirements for these additional stringencies.

Comment: Just because it has ou this does not mean it's pas yisroel fit for Shabbos purposes, so Jewish people should rather make their own challah or buy from a Jewish owned bakery that takes the  Challah portion.

Comment: @yosefkorn Pas Yisroel and yoshon are explicitly addressed in the answer. Also, this question isn't about Shabbos.

Comment: I'm sorry but in most places Non kosher stores for mass produced commercially baked products the ou sign is unnoticable and there is no indication of Pas Yisroel, and what happens in most of the world where ou is not at all on the pakage including in the questioners case? you have no basis for your answer rather you base yourself on the fact that in atlanta where you live mass baked bread is Pas Yisroel. Also the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch specifically says to get bread owned and baked by a Jew that has challa taken from it. This is not the case when its owned by a Gentile

Comment: @user15464 if there's no hechsher it's not kosher. That's clear from my answer. I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: My point is that the Kitzur (see my answer) says one should buy Pas Yisroel challa for Shabbos where as you are saying just get bread with ou on it which is Pas Palter unless you find out otherwise (which you misinformed people that bread with ou is Pas Yisroel ), The Question was regards to Challa not bread eaten during the week. Also you have misinformed people

Comment: @user15464 the kitzur (and others) recommend pas yosroel for Shabbos but this is not a universal practice and certainly cannot be considered obligatory. I never said supermarket bread was pas Yisroel and I did mention that some Jews observe these additional stringencies. Challah can be eaten any day of the week and the questioner gave no indication that he/she was asking about Shabbos or had even heard of it.

Comment: @doniel i think that every frum Jew that lives near a Jewish Bakery buys Challa from  Jewish bakery for Shabbos unless they bake themselves, to just push aside a Tradition which is accepted and ignore the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch without any sources, means that you should CYLOR and i hope that he can persuade you  to get Pas Yisroel for Shabbos as i have tried to convince you ...maybe he'll have more success

Comment: @user15464 once again, nothing indicates this question is about Shabbos.

Comment: I'm trying to provide a simple answer to a basic question. "Can Jews buy bread from Whole Foods?" The answer is "if it's kosher."

Comment: @Daniel look at the tag Challa-Shabbos-bread clearly the right honorable person asking was not talking about regular bread

Answer (score -1):

"Challah" is a coined term for the bread Jewish people have a tradition to eat on Shabbos. The name Challah is actually in reference to the portion that is separated for the ritually pure Cohen (when baking minimum 2.2kg of flour) but nowadays a Cohen may not eat his portion because we don't have the ashes of the red cow to purify ourselves, so wrap that piece and dispose of it in a respectful way.

Even though during the week Jewish people are permitted to buy bread that is Kosher from superstores to eat as this is *Pas Palter* (bread baked en masse, see SA Rema YD 112,2), on Shabbos we have a tradition either ideally for the woman of the house to
bake her own bread, or if not possible to buy bread baked by Jews (i'm assuming this would not be the case in "whole foods" and other superstores chains) where the portion for the Cohen *challa* has been Separated as a sign of respect for the holy Shabbos day.

The reason why the Mitzva of seperating *challa* was placed on the Jewish woman, is because Eve cause Adam who was the *Challa* separation of the earth (i.e the most holy servant of G-d just like the Cohen is the Holy servant of G-d) to sin and lose his life so women rectify that sin by separating part of the bread which is Holy for the Cohen.

Source Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 72,6

> אם אוכלים בימי החול פת פלטר עובד כוכבים, שיש ליזהר לאכול ביום השבת קודש פת ישראל
>
> כבוד שבת – יאפו בביתו, כדי שתקיים האשה מצות הפרשת חלה. כי אדם הראשון נברא בערב שבת, והיה חלתו של עולם, והאשה בחטאה – איבדתו; ועל כן צריכה היא לתקן דבר זה

Comment: I'm not sure your assumption that Whole Foods' challah is _pas palter_ is correct. I don't know where Whole Foods sources their challah from but certainly other supermarkets do offer challah which is _pas Yisrael_. For example, Trader Joe's (at least in the Midwestern United States) sources their challah from North Shore Bakery in Chicago which is _pas Yisrael_. The Kroger near my house in Atlanta offers _pas Yisrael_ challah.

Comment: Also, eating _pas Yisrael_ on Shabbos is a widespread practice, but I certainly don't think it's a _chiyuv_. Not everybody is strict about this.

Comment: @Daniel i can't help thinking that you didn't read my post as you prefer you own answer which is understandable. I never defined whole foods for sure as pas palter i just assumed it would be so if it was kosher (we should assume an average superstore unless otherwise known does _not_ have Jewish people turning the oven on) . I said  we have a tradition not an obligation to use bread baked by a Jew that has had Challa taken from it

Comment: I did read your post. I don't think it's exactly wrong. Just not very clear. That's why I posted my own answer, which I think is easier to understand (especially for someone who is unfamiliar with basic _halakhic_ terminology).

Comment: I know you didn't assert that bread from Whole Foods is definitely _pas palter_. I was just commenting that I don't think your assumption is really a given. These breads are often not baked in the supermarket. They're sourced from somewhere else and put in supermarket-branded packaging.

Comment: the main reason to use pas yisroel on shabbos is exactly that: to use pas yisroel.[לע'ד]      taking challah off is another reason but dont make the ikkar tafel and the tafel ikkar