# Does the 16th of Shevat have any halachic effects?

Tags: chutz-laaretz, safek, tu-bishvat

For most Torah holidays, we keep two days outside Israel out of doubt.

Tu bishvat is a day with Biblical effects (though I wouldn't go so far as to say it's a Biblical "holiday", or a Rabbinic one either for that matter): it affects the Torah laws of maaser and orlah.

However, these laws are only in full force in Israel.  Orlah applies mideoraisa everywhere due to a halacha lemoshe misinai, but is permitted outside Israel in a case of doubt, so it would probably be permitted on the 16th of Shevat.  Maaser applies in a few places outside Israel, but in those places it's only Rabbinic, so I would guess that we would be lenient for the doubtful day (I may be wrong).

Are there any effects outside Israel of "the second day of Tu Bishvat"?

Comment: Some possibilities, which I don't know the halacha well enough to confirm: if you carry a tree out of Israel in a flowerpot with holes in the bottom, making sure to stay over dirt the whole time?  Or if you receive shipments of esrogim from Israel labeled "Picked on February 10, 2020" and "Picked on February 11, 2020"?

Comment: NO TACHANUN!!!!!1!!!!!1!!

Comment: @DoubleAA that's not my motivation for asking (though if the answer is yes I wouldn't be surprised if somebody used it as an excuse to make up another new day to not say tachanun)

Comment: What about Revai? Fruit picked on 16 Shevat could be Safek Orlah / Safek Revai and therefore neither? Or maybe Podeh without Bracha? (accd to opinions revai exists in chul)

Comment: What about in Syria? Safek Orlah is not as permitted there as in the rest of the diaspora and we know they didn't send messengers for Shevat so even in Syria they'd have had doubts?

Comment: I'd venture to say that there's no practical difference since Tu Bishvat's _cut off_ depends on the fruit's Chanita. - See [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_%D7%97%D6%B6%D7%A0%D6%B6%D7%98.1) for various explanations of Chanita, as well as the [Drisha](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Drisha%2C_Yoreh_Deah.294.2.1?vhe=Tur_Yoreh_Deah,_Vilna,_1923&with=Tur) who says that no Chanita happens nowadays before TuB. Point being, it's probably impossible to get up on TuB and declare "hey this tree has done Chanita and this hasn't." One extra day won't help either, so why bother.

Comment: @danny I'm pretty sure the Drisha was talking before there were greenhouses.  Plus for esrogim it goes by when you pick them

Comment: @Heshy - correct, but even with greenhouses (1) it's still "impossible" IIUC to pinpoint Chanita to within a few hours/days and (2) the Esrog picking Halacha is before/after 1 Tishrei IIRC. Not Tubishvat related.

Comment: @danny https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Heave_Offerings.5.11

Comment: @Heshy, I stand corrected (for a change) - וְכֵן אִם לִקֵּט אֶתְרוֹג בְּעֶרֶב ט''ו בִּשְׁבָט עַד שֶׁלֹּא בָּא הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ וְחָזַר וְלִקֵּט אֶתְרוֹג אַחֵר מִשֶּׁבָּאָה הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ אֵין תּוֹרְמִין מִזֶּה עַל זֶה מִפְּנֵי שֶׁאֶחָד בְּתִשְׁרֵי רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה לְמַעַשְׂרוֹת תְּבוּאָה וְקִטְנִיּוֹת וִירָקוֹת. וְט''ו בִּשְׁבָט רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה לְמַעַשְׂרוֹת הָאִילָן